# Android - Fragment 2 Displaying back the main fragment with Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

From the main fragment  I opened VideoPlayerFragment, in VideoPlayerFragment when I press a button it should go back to the parent fragment.

```
CollectionDemoActivity{

class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends ListFragments{

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

String fragMainGroups = "mainGroups";


                    Fragment fragment1 = new VideoPlayerFragment();

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragMainGroups );
                    transaction.addToBackStack(fragMainGroups);
                    transaction.commit(); 

      }
   }
}
```

**External Class**

**VideoPlayerFragment.java**

class VideoPlayerFragment extends ListFragment{

```
            @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                            String Groups = "Groups";

                            Fragment fragment1 = new CollectionDemoActivity.LaunchpadSectionFragment();

                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.layout.load_main_groups_activty, fragment1, Groups);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(Groups);
                            transaction.commit(); 

             }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use this code below to open the previous fragment from backstack using its fragment tag.

```
String fragMainGroups = "mainGroups";
                            String Groups = "Groups";

                            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragMainGroups);                                              


                            if (fragment != null) // could be null if not instantiated yet
                            {
                                if (fragment.getView() != null) {
                                    // Pop the backstack on the ChildManager if there is any. If not, close this activity as normal.
                                    if (!fragment.getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
                                        fragment.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                                        //getActivity().finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```